# How to increase the screen saturation in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: intel-graphics, screen

i've been using Ubuntu for almost a week now. Is there a way to increase the colour saturation of the OS. I used to do it with Intel graphics settings in Windows 10. Can i do the same thing here ? Is there a way to install the intel software in Ubuntu rather than the preinstalled one ?.

Comment: Are you unable to achieve the desired saturation by adjusting your monitor's settings?

Answer (score 1):

A roundabout way for increasing saturation in Ubuntu (22.04 and possibly in 20.04) is to use settings/accessibility/zoom options. Set zoom to 1 (default) and increase saturation with a slider. Switch zoom on (Super + left Alt + 8) then decrease zoom to zero (Super + left Alt + "minus key"). This way your screen has permanent zero zoom with saturation. If you want to zoom-in-out all you have to do is to press (Super + left Alt + "plus key" or "minus key"). After restart zoom needs to be switched back on. Switching off zoom switches off saturation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your calibration device is connected to your computer
2. Open Activities overview and start typing settings
3. click on settings
4. click color in the sidebar to open the panel
5. select screen
6. press calibrate

for more help this thread is on https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/color-calibrate-screen.html.en

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But i was looking for a more simple solution like in Windows using the intel settings instead of using a seperate calibration device.

Comment: @ADWYT how have you done that?